# Chrome not throwing Javascript syntax error on Developer console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, syntax-error, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a project. So there were multiple syntax error inside the code like:

- forgot to add comma after key value pair:

  ```
  {
    test: 'test1'
    test2: 'test2'
  }
  ```
- Or logging undefined variable:

  ```
  console.log(test)
  ```

When I set debug point to above console.log, it correctly says "Reference Error: Undefined variable" on hover the variable. But it doesn't print the error on console.
Becoming really hard to debug the syntax error code.

I have checked the type of message to display on console, in dropdown. "Info", "Warning", "Errors" are selected.

[image]

Note: If I create new file and add buggy code. It works fine in chrome (as in correctly throwing error).

Comment: did you tried printing a string along with the finalObj to check if the console log is executed properly

Comment: Works fine for me, https://jsfiddle.net/t29enjqL/. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: Are you filtering the errors out of the log? Also, the first snippet should not even throw any error, it's just a block of code with a couple of labels.

Comment: Perhaps you are navigating away so the errors are cleared?

Comment: I know it's not the issue with Chrome specifically, something related to my javascript file may be. Everything works fine till the buggy code. console.log working before buggy code. And I am not filtering the errors, have mentioned that "info, warning, errors" are selected.